# Dailymotion iframe api

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am using dailymotion api to play videos. Example is straight from the docs:

http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/player.html#api-reference

And its giving me errors in console:

```
<!-- This <div> tag will be replaced the <iframe> video player -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
// This code loads the Dailymotion Javascript SDK asynchronously.
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//api.dmcdn.net/all.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
}());

// This function init the player once the SDK is loaded
window.dmAsyncInit = function()
{
    // PARAMS is a javascript object containing parameters to pass to the player if any (eg: {autoplay: 1})
    var player = DM.player("player", {video: "x1bpnpt", width: "640", height: "360", params: {autoplay: 1}});

    // 4. We can attach some events on the player (using standard DOM events)
    player.addEventListener("apiready", function(e)
    {
        e.target.play();
    });
};
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WpbJH/

But if I embed it directly in iframe then it works (it also displays some errors but not the ones from above):

```
<iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x1bpnpt?api=true&autoplay=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MWhdC/

What is wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you add the errors you get in both cases ? It might help people to understand. Also, are you testing on mobile or desktop?

Comment: Everything seems to work fine when I test both jsfiddle links you sent (I also see the erros in the console in the first case, but doesn't seem to impact the video playback). 

Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As i am looking on it , js file is not proper loaded , please look at 
`e.src = document.location.protocol + '//api.dmcdn.net/all.js';` line

`document.location.protocol` prefix domain infront of  **//api.dmcdn.net/all.js** .

So please look at it and let me know .

Answer (score 0):

After few research, I found what cause this issue.

The video they are using as example gets report from third party advertising group, and need to report to it every step of the video.

Upload a video of your own, and use the id you get from it, you will see that you will not have console errors.

Hope that was helpful.